# mongodb: how to check which node I connected on replicaSet

Tags: java, mongodb, database-replication

I configured 3 machines with MongoDB ReplicaSet, and all is working great, I can connect to them, one of them dies and the remaining keep working, it is fine.

I connect with the URI: `hostname1,hostname2,hostname3/?readPreference=secondary`, then I make some queries and they are working as well, but I want to check if this connection is really querying from the secondary node.

How can I check this? Should I just trust that this is being done this way?, I also was checking the logs on the machines with mongo, and all of them, show the same things, that the connection was made to all three (connection accepted from REMOTEIP #NUMBER).

I also made a quick test with Java, and reading the `db.getReadPreference()` from the `com.mongo.DB` I configured, and it is showing secondary. So it is the same, should I then trust this? is it correctly querying only the secondary node?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) use mongostat command, which will tell you how many different operations ( query, insert, update, delete, command, etc ) are coming to the server
You will find that primary is not getting any 'query' operation but secondaries will.

```
mongostat -u<user-name> -p<password>
```

2) Use mongosniff, to know the queries coming to the server

Comment: Thank you, I used `mongostat --port PORT` by default, no users. Queries only made to secondaries, I can trust now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use mongotop
syntax: mongotop -h ip:port seconds  // seconds: int value to refesh the dashboard
ex:     mongotop -h 127.0.0.1:27017 5
```